# How to mark main dependency as "compile" and sub-dependencies as "provide"?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

One of my Android projects requires `oauth.signpost` artifact, so I have something like this in my `pom.xml`:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
    <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

The problem is that this depends on more artifacts, for instance: `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1`. The problem is that Android already provides that package and thus it makes my building process crash.

So, what I usually do is going to the dependencies configuration on IntelliJ and manually mark those redundant artifacts as *provide* instead of *compile*:

[image: intellij dependencies]

This process is annoying, not only because I have a lot of Maven dependencies, but also because sometimes IntelliJ *forgets* what dependencies were market as *provide* and it will mark'em all as *compile*.

The only solution I see is to specify, in the `pom.xml`, which dependencies are *provide* and which are *compile*. But there are a lot of them, so it would take some time (also, I'd have to manually check which version is needed for each artifact, etc.).

So, is it a way to tell Maven to mark sub-dependencies as *provide*, while keeping main dependencies as *compile*?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without specifying them as _provided_ in the pom.xml. You should only need to do it once though.

Answer (score 2):

There is the option to add dependency exclusions.

Consider the following:

- Let's assume you have two projects - bar and foo.
- Bar dependends on log4j.
- You would like foo to depend on a different version of log4j.

This would be your pom.xml in the foo module:

```
<project>
  <groupId>kung.fu</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>kung.fu</groupId>
      <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```